# How to handle this error with firebase_auth, flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Im trying to link accounts credentials using firebase_auth, google_sing_in and facebook_login packages, but i dont know how to handle this error, the fetchSignInMethodsForEmail requires an email and the error callback doesnt return any. Please help

This is the error:

> PlatformException(ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL, An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address., null)

This is the documentation in the source code:

> ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL - If there already
>   exists an account with the email address asserted by Google. Resolve
>   this case by calling [fetchSignInMethodsForEmail] and then asking the
>   user to sign in using one of them.

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text.  It's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: question updated